# iTunes Connect App vs Support URL: which one is which?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, the meta data of an app indicates two URL fields:

*App URL*
and 
*Support URL (optional)*

When viewing the app page from a regular browser, however, there are two URL fields that are differently labeled:

*(company) website* and *(app) support*

Which one is which? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [iPhone Devleopment 101](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/checklist.html):

> **iTunes Connect calls it:**   --> **What it shows on your app's page in iTunes:**
>
> "Application URL" --> "CompanyName Web
>   Site"
>
> "Support URL" --> "Appname Support"

Comment: The only three URLs I can change are:

Support URL, Marketing URL (Optional), Privacy Policy URL (Optional). Non of which seems to change the CompanyName Web Site, and I but really change it. For some reason the link is "http:/"

Comment: I was having the same problem. Use the Marketing URL (optional) field in your app's metadata section. Intuitive right?